# ValidateAntiForgeryToken doesn't do the only thing it is suppose to do

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages, antiforgerytoken

I am implementing AntiForgeryToken feature to my asp.net core mvc project. As usual, I have included `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` inside the form tags so it looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="mycontroller/myaction">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input type="text" name="myInput"/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and as you can imagine, here is the *myaction* action in my *mycontroller* controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("somepath")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult myaction()
{
    //some code here
}
```

Now the problem is, **I NEVER GET ANY ERROR!!**

I removed the `@Html.AntiForgeryToken` from the view and the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` doesn't do a thing! the post action works just fine.

Here are two things I have tried that might give you a clue:

1. I tried both `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` and `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]`, no difference!
2. Someone said that the attribute only works in *authorized* controllers or actions. Tried this in my controller that has the `[Authorize]` tag.

**PS: I have not added any code in my `Startup.cs` like `services.AddMvc(...)`. Could it be something about that??**

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In and MVC app (which you have there), request verification using an anti forgery token is opt in. You opt in by decorating the controller action with the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute. If you omit the attribute, the request is not subject to verification. In each of the scenarios you described, there is no reason for an error. The only time you are likely to see an error (in the shape of a 400 HTTP status code) in an MVC app is if you decorate the action with the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute but the cookie or token are not included as part of the request payload.

In Razor Pages, all POST requests are verified by default. You can opt out of request verification, in which case you can opt in on a page by page basis by adding the attribute to the PageModel class (not the handler method) The anti-forgery token is generated by the form tag helper when the method is set to POST in both Razor Pages and MVC views.

Sometimes, you might want to post without a form (using AJAX most commonly) in which case you need to generate the anti-forgery token in the view so that you can include it within the post request payload. The `Html.AntiforgeryToken` helper (which is a legacy from older versions of MVC) provides a convenient way to do that.

I've written in detail about this process here: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/security/request-verification

Comment: Well if there are verified by default, why is there an @Html.AntiForgeryToken tag in the first place?

Comment: @xandune I've update my answer with more information

Comment: thanks so much for the information. Just to verify what I have learned: MVC automatically checks each form with post method for antiforgery. This is by default. Html.AntiForgeryToken comes useful when we use AJAX to post without a form. If I opt out antiforgery verification, I do that in `Startup.cs` with `services.AddRazorPages() ...` . By the way, I have used your site **www.mikesdotnetting.com/** for numerous occasions and am surprised to see that you have answered my question!! Thanks man

Comment: Per Microsoft documentation, "Calling AddControllers does not enable antiforgery tokens. AddControllersWithViews must be called to have built-in antiforgery token support." So to confirm, using AddControllersWithViews, the token is added to the form in the view by defauIt (when using the formtaghelper), and I won't have to add the ValidateAntiForgeryToken action filter to the action method as it will also be implicit correct? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

ValidateAntiForgeryToken is used to prevent cross-site request forgery attacks.

Antiforgery middleware has been added to the Dependency injection container when services.AddMvc() is called,and The FormTagHelper has injected antiforgery tokens into HTML form elements already.You don't need to call  `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`

For more details ,you could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: So let me get this right. @Html.AntiForgeryToken() is unnecessary because services.AddMvc() automatically does the same job?

Comment: @xandune Not quite. The antiforgery token helper renders a hidden form field to the browser containing the value of the anti forgery token. So does a form tag helper if you set the form method to `post`. `AddMvc` or `AddRazorPages` includes middleware to the app that actually performs the request verification check.

Comment: @MikeBrind correct me if I'm wrong. So if I dont manually include an Html.AntiForgeryToken inside my form, a form tag helper would do the same job automatically when my form tags have method="post" in them? Or in other words, simply not including Html.AntiForgeryToken would not cause a breach in security? Sorry if my questions sound dumb, I am not very well knowledged in this subject